# How to make GUI and Window reappear on Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In the absolute stellar form, I spent hours making a GUI in Visual Basic Express 2008, When I reopen the files all I get is the code and text rather than the form. It is not the end of the world but I am worried I might need to make amendments to the GUI but will have to make from scratch now as I cannot reaccess it.

- Here is what I see when I open the files

[image]

- Here is what I could view and edit yesterday, this is what I want to get back to

[image]

Comment: VBA is not the same as VB.Net. Please don't re-add the VBA tag in.

Comment: I changed the way I worded the question and thought I had missed out the tag, I stand corrected. I appreciate VB express 2008 is outdated but was hoping I had missed something simple as this was my first time using

Comment: also I worked out I need to right click and select run designer however this option does not seem to be available.